# JavaScript - wrong float values comparison

Tags: javascript, forms

There are two fields - faceValue `fv2` and askingPrice `num2` - and askingPrice can't be less than faceValue.

The check is almost working, but with a face value of 10.00, the alert only triggers when the asking price is 1.00 (9.00, 8.00 etc etc don't trigger it). However, when fv2 reloads into the form it's correct - 10.00.

How to fix this issue? here's the code

```
            // new askingPrice comparison

            var fv2 = parseFloat($('.ticketFaceValue').val()).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
            var num2 = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');

            if (num2 < fv2) {
            alert('Sorry, your asking price can\'t be less than face value. Please change your asking price.');

            $(this).val(fv2);
            row.find('.askingPriceData').html(fv2);
            recalculateFees();
          }

            // end new askingPrice comparison
```

Comment: Would you tell me why you are using replace...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you use `parseFloat` to convert the input string to a number type, you convert it back to string with `toFixed`, and so the comparison is character based, not by numerical value.

The thing you try to do with a `replace` (add thousands separators) can also be done with `toLocaleString`, but you need to take care to not to put that formatted string back into the `input` element, as it will not parse as a number. It is probably better to use separate variables for the numerical value and the formatted value. Maybe like this:

```
var fv2 = +$('.ticketFaceValue').val()
var num2 = +$(this).val();
var fv2Fmt =fv2.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});
var num2Fmt =num2.toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2});

if (num2 < fv2) {
    alert('Sorry, your asking price can\'t be less than face value. Please change your asking price.');

    $(this).val(fv2);
    row.find('.askingPriceData').html(fv2Fmt);
    recalculateFees();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, using @trincot suggestion has worked v. well. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`toFixed()` method returns string so you are comparing two strings. Try the below code.

```
var fv2_float = parseFloat($('.ticketFaceValue').val()); 
var num2_float = parseFloat($(this).val());      

var fv2 = fv2_float.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');
var num2 = num2_float.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');

if (num2_float < fv2_float) {
   // Do your staff
}
```

Or try below one, but this is not very efficient.

```
// Your code goes here

if (parseFloat(num2) < parseFloat(fv2)) {
   // Do your staff
}
```